# Azure power shell cmdlet: Login-AzureRmAccount interactive doesn't work on windows server R8

Tags: shell, powershell, azure

**PowerShell Version**

3.0

**Azrue powershell Module Version**

3.7.0

**OS Version**

Windows Server R8

**Description**

Interactive Login does not work. Login seems successful but power shell doesn't login. Already disabled IE ESC

**Debug Output**

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : Service returned error. Check InnerException for more details: The underlying connection was
closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
At line:1 char:1

Login-AzureRmAccount
  + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand
```

Comment: Hi, the VM is used Azure image or your custom image?

Comment: What is your R8 version? I upgrade PowerShell from 2.0 to 5.0. `login-azurermaccount` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could upgrade your PowerShell to 5.0. PowerShell 5.0 supports Windows 2008R2SP1. You could download it from the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395).

Notes: Please select `Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu` when you download installer file.

If it also does not work, you could try to reinstall Azure PowerShell, you could install the latest version .msi file from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v3.7.0-March2017).

Update:

You should  installed Windows Management framework 5.1, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203892/import-module-azurerm-import-module-the-specified-module-azurerm-was-not-loa/48204044#48204044).

Comment: Hi , yeah , I am using 3.0 powershell. The minimum on Powershell github page seems to be 3.0. Shall try 5.0.

Comment: Tried it with 5.0. It throws the same error. Tried Add-AzureRMAccount as well,  same.

Comment: @nwarriorch Hi, I update my answer, you should install Windows Management framework 5.1 on Windows 8.