# Import-Module AzureRM Import-Module : The specified module 'AzureRM' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to execute this:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Login-AzureRmAccount : The term 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
```

I installed on Windows 8, Azure Powershell using platform instaler.

After restarting I get the module names:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable





    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-PackageSource...}                                                                                                                                 
Script     1.1.3.2    PowerShellGet                       {Install-Module, Find-Module, Save-Module, Update-Module...}                                                                                                                                           
Binary     2.17.17... SharePointPnPPowerShell2013         {Add-PnPContentType, Add-PnPContentTypeToDocumentSet, Add-PnPContentTypeToList, Add-PnPCustomAction...}                                                                                                


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Script     0.5.0      Azure.AnalysisServices              {Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount, Restart-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance, Export-AzureAnalysisServicesInstanceLog, Sync-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance...}                                              
Script     0.6.1      AzureRM.AnalysisServices            {Resume-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer, Suspend-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer, Get-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer, Remove-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer...}                                              
Script     5.0.1      AzureRM.ApiManagement               {Add-AzureRmApiManagementRegion, Get-AzureRmApiManagementSsoToken, New-AzureRmApiManagementHostnameConfiguration, New-AzureRmApiManagementRegion...}                                                   
Script     0.1.0      AzureRM.ApplicationInsights         {Get-AzureRmApplicationInsights, New-AzureRmApplicationInsights, Remove-AzureRmApplicationInsights, Set-AzureRmApplicationInsightsPricingPlan...}                                                      
Script     4.1.1      AzureRM.Automation                  {Get-AzureRMAutomationHybridWorkerGroup, Get-AzureRmAutomationJobOutputRecord, Import-AzureRmAutomationDscNodeConfiguration, Export-AzureRmAutomationDscConfiguration...}                              
Script     4.0.1      AzureRM.Backup                      {Backup-AzureRmBackupItem, Enable-AzureRmBackupContainerReregistration, Get-AzureRmBackupContainer, Register-AzureRmBackupContainer...}                                                                
Script     4.0.3      AzureRM.Batch                       {Remove-AzureRmBatchAccount, Get-AzureRmBatchAccount, Get-AzureRmBatchAccountKeys, New-AzureRmBatchAccount...}                                                                                         
Script     0.14.0     AzureRM.Billing                     {Get-AzureRmBillingInvoice, Get-AzureRmBillingPeriod}                                                                                                                                                  
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.Cdn                         {Get-AzureRmCdnProfile, Get-AzureRmCdnProfileSsoUrl, New-AzureRmCdnProfile, Remove-AzureRmCdnProfile...}                                                                                               
Script     0.9.0      AzureRM.CognitiveServices           {Get-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccount, Get-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccountKey, Get-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccountSkus, New-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccount...}                                         
Script     4.1.1      AzureRM.Compute                     {Remove-AzureRmAvailabilitySet, Get-AzureRmAvailabilitySet, New-AzureRmAvailabilitySet, Update-AzureRmAvailabilitySet...}                                                                              
Script     0.3.0      AzureRM.Consumption                 Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail                                                                                                                                                                      
Script     0.2.1      AzureRM.ContainerInstance           {New-AzureRmContainerGroup, Get-AzureRmContainerGroup, Remove-AzureRmContainerGroup, Get-AzureRmContainerInstanceLog}                                                                                  
Script     1.0.1      AzureRM.ContainerRegistry           {New-AzureRmContainerRegistry, Get-AzureRmContainerRegistry, Update-AzureRmContainerRegistry, Remove-AzureRmContainerRegistry...}                                                                      
Script     4.0.3      AzureRM.DataFactories               {Remove-AzureRmDataFactory, Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun, Get-AzureRmDataFactorySlice, Save-AzureRmDataFactoryLog...}                                                                                     
Script     0.4.1      AzureRM.DataFactoryV2               {Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2, Update-AzureRmDataFactoryV2, Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2, Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2...}                                                                                      
Script     4.1.1      AzureRM.DataLakeAnalytics           {Get-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsDataSource, New-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogCredential, Remove-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogCredential, Remove-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogSecret...}             
Script     5.0.0      AzureRM.DataLakeStore               {Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreTrustedIdProvider, Remove-AzureRmDataLakeStoreTrustedIdProvider, Remove-AzureRmDataLakeStoreFirewallRule, Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreTrustedIdProvider...}                       
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.DevTestLabs                 {Get-AzureRmDtlAllowedVMSizesPolicy, Get-AzureRmDtlAutoShutdownPolicy, Get-AzureRmDtlAutoStartPolicy, Get-AzureRmDtlVMsPerLabPolicy...}                                                                
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.Dns                         {Get-AzureRmDnsRecordSet, New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig, Remove-AzureRmDnsRecordSet, Set-AzureRmDnsRecordSet...}                                                                                          
Script     0.2.0      AzureRM.EventGrid                   {New-AzureRmEventGridTopic, Get-AzureRmEventGridTopic, Set-AzureRmEventGridTopic, New-AzureRmEventGridTopicKey...}                                                                                     
Script     0.5.0      AzureRM.EventHub                    {New-AzureRmEventHubNamespace, Get-AzureRmEventHubNamespace, Set-AzureRmEventHubNamespace, Remove-AzureRmEventHubNamespace...}                                                                         
Script     4.0.1      AzureRM.HDInsight                   {Get-AzureRmHDInsightJob, New-AzureRmHDInsightSqoopJobDefinition, Wait-AzureRmHDInsightJob, New-AzureRmHDInsightStreamingMapReduceJobDefinition...}                                                    
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.Insights                    {Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition, Get-AzureRmMetric, Remove-AzureRmLogProfile, Get-AzureRmLogProfile...}                                                                                                   
Script     3.0.0      AzureRM.IotHub                      {Add-AzureRmIotHubKey, Get-AzureRmIotHubEventHubConsumerGroup, Get-AzureRmIotHubConnectionString, Get-AzureRmIotHubJob...}                                                                             
Script     4.0.1      AzureRM.KeyVault                    {Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate, Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificateAttribute, Stop-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation, Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation...}                                                
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.LogicApp                    {Get-AzureRmIntegrationAccountAgreement, Get-AzureRmIntegrationAccountCallbackUrl, Get-AzureRmIntegrationAccountCertificate, Get-AzureRmIntegrationAccount...}                                         
Script     0.16.0     AzureRM.MachineLearning             {Move-AzureRmMlCommitmentAssociation, Get-AzureRmMlCommitmentAssociation, Get-AzureRmMlCommitmentPlanUsageHistory, Remove-AzureRmMlCommitmentPlan...}                                                  
Script     0.3.1      AzureRM.MachineLearningCompute      {Get-AzureRmMlOpCluster, Get-AzureRmMlOpClusterKey, Test-AzureRmMlOpClusterSystemServicesUpdateAvailability, Update-AzureRmMlOpClusterSystemService...}                                                
Script     0.2.0      AzureRM.MarketplaceOrdering         {Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms, Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms}                                                                                                                                             
Script     0.8.0      AzureRM.Media                       {Sync-AzureRmMediaServiceStorageKeys, Set-AzureRmMediaServiceKey, Get-AzureRmMediaServiceKeys, Get-AzureRmMediaServiceNameAvailability...}                                                             
Script     5.0.0      AzureRM.Network                     {Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, New-AzureRmApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, Remove-AzureRmApplicationGa...
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.NotificationHubs            {Get-AzureRmNotificationHub, Get-AzureRmNotificationHubAuthorizationRules, Get-AzureRmNotificationHubListKeys, Get-AzureRmNotificationHubPNSCredentials...}                                            
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.OperationalInsights         {New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource, New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsCustomLogDataSource, Disable-AzureRmOperationalInsightsLinuxCustomLogCollection, Disable-AzureRmOperational...
Script     4.1.1      AzureRM.PowerBIEmbedded             {Remove-AzureRmPowerBIWorkspaceCollection, Get-AzureRmPowerBIWorkspaceCollection, Get-AzureRmPowerBIWorkspaceCollectionAccessKeys, Get-AzureRmPowerBIWorkspace...}                                     
Script     4.1.1      AzureRM.Profile                     {Disable-AzureRmDataCollection, Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave, Enable-AzureRmDataCollection, Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave...}                                                                        
Script     4.0.1      AzureRM.RecoveryServices            {Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProperty, Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault, Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultSettingsFile, New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault...}                                       
Script     4.0.3      AzureRM.RecoveryServices.Backup     {Backup-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem, Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupManagementServer, Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer, Unregister-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer...}        
Script     0.2.1      AzureRM.RecoveryServices.SiteRec... {Edit-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan, Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrAlertSetting, Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrEvent, Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrFabric...}                                
Script     4.0.1      AzureRM.RedisCache                  {Remove-AzureRmRedisCachePatchSchedule, New-AzureRmRedisCacheScheduleEntry, Get-AzureRmRedisCachePatchSchedule, New-AzureRmRedisCachePatchSchedule...}                                                 
Script     0.3.0      AzureRM.Relay                       {New-AzureRmRelayNamespace, Get-AzureRmRelayNamespace, Set-AzureRmRelayNamespace, Remove-AzureRmRelayNamespace...}                                                                                     
Script     5.1.1      AzureRM.Resources                   {Get-AzureRmProviderOperation, Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment, Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment, New-AzureRmRoleAssignment...}                                                                                  
Script     0.16.0     AzureRM.Scheduler                   {Disable-AzureRmSchedulerJobCollection, Enable-AzureRmSchedulerJobCollection, Get-AzureRmSchedulerJobCollection, Get-AzureRmSchedulerJob...}                                                           
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.ServerManagement            {Invoke-AzureRmServerManagementPowerShellCommand, Get-AzureRmServerManagementSession, New-AzureRmServerManagementSession, Remove-AzureRmServerManagementSession...}                                    
Script     0.5.0      AzureRM.ServiceBus                  {New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace, Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace, Set-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace, Remove-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace...}                                                                 
Script     0.3.0      AzureRM.ServiceFabric               {Add-AzureRmServiceFabricApplicationCertificate, Add-AzureRmServiceFabricClientCertificate, Add-AzureRmServiceFabricClusterCertificate, Add-AzureRmServiceFabricNode...}                               
Script     5.0.3      AzureRM.SiteRecovery                {Get-AzureRmSiteRecoveryFabric, New-AzureRmSiteRecoveryFabric, Remove-AzureRmSiteRecoveryFabric, Stop-AzureRmSiteRecoveryJob...}                                                                       
Script     4.1.1      AzureRM.Sql                         {Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption, Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryptionActivity, Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption, Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseUpgradeHint...}      
Script     4.0.1      AzureRM.Storage                     {Get-AzureRmStorageAccount, Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey, New-AzureRmStorageAccount, New-AzureRmStorageAccountKey...}                                                                                  
Script     4.0.1      AzureRM.StreamAnalytics             {Get-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsFunction, Get-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsDefaultFunctionDefinition, New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsFunction, Remove-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsFunction...}                                
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.Tags                        {Remove-AzureRmTag, Get-AzureRmTag, New-AzureRmTag}                                                                                                                                                    
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.TrafficManager              {Disable-AzureRmTrafficManagerEndpoint, Enable-AzureRmTrafficManagerEndpoint, Set-AzureRmTrafficManagerEndpoint, Get-AzureRmTrafficManagerEndpoint...}                                                 
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.UsageAggregates             Get-UsageAggregates                                                                                                                                                                                    
Script     4.0.0      AzureRM.Websites                    {Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan, Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan, New-AzureRmAppServicePlan, Remove-AzureRmAppServicePlan...}                                                                                     


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Script     5.1.1      Azure                               {Get-AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnection, New-AzureAutomationConnection, Remove-AzureAutomationConnection...}                                                                    


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\Storage


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Script     4.0.2      Azure.Storage                       {Get-AzureStorageTable, New-AzureStorageTableSASToken, New-AzureStorageTableStoredAccessPolicy, New-AzureStorageTable...}
```

Update1

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell> Get-Module

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Script     5.1.1      Azure                               {Add-AzureAccount, Add-AzureApplicationGatewaySslCertificate, Add-AzureCertificate, Add-AzureDataDisk...}                                                                                              
Script     0.5.0      Azure.AnalysisServices              {Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount, Export-AzureAnalysisServicesInstanceLog, Restart-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance, Sync-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance}                                                 
Script     4.0.2      Azure.Storage                       {Get-AzureStorageBlob, Get-AzureStorageBlobContent, Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState, Get-AzureStorageContainer...}                                                                                       
Script     4.1.1      AzureRM.Profile                     {Add-AzureRmAccount, Add-AzureRmEnvironment, Clear-AzureRmContext, Clear-AzureRmDefault...}                                                                                                            
Script     1.0.0.0    ISE                                 {Get-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, New-IseSnippet}                                                                                                                                                    
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}                                                                                                                                     
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
```

Import-Module AzureRM (doesnt work), moduloe not loaded
Import-Module Azure (does work)

Comment: I see that the first command "Login-AzureRmAccount" was failing.  To connect to Azure I use the command: "Connect-AzAccount".

Comment: Also, the AzureRm modules will be retired by Microsoft on 29th February 2024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Azure SDK and it didnt work, then I installed  Windows Management framework 5.1 and restarted, then the command worked!

Answer (score 6):

We can install Azure powershell with MSI, we can download [Azure powershell 5.1.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v5.1.1-December2017/azure-powershell.5.1.1.msi) from here.

Just download it then install it.

More information about Azure Powershell release, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: I downloaded the MSI and then run a repair. I still get the same thing, Login-AzureRmAccount : The term 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: @LuisValencia Please wait, I will check it:)

Comment: remove it how, using webplatform installer? program and features? some powershell cmdlet?

Comment: @LuisValencia use that MSI,

Comment: @LuisValencia Please try this command `Install-Module AzureRM -AllowClobber`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162972/discussion-between-luis-valencia-and-jason-ye-msft).